# new commands in html with MathJAX

Tags: html, command, mathjax

When you are in LaTex, to add a new command you write it in the preamble, for example, you can write

```
\newcommand{\conj}{\wedge}
```

then, when you put `\conj`in your document if you compile it appears the same as with `\wedge`. How can I do something like this in html if I am using MathJAX?

Comment: Not answering your question but just know that Mathjax is not the same as Latex. It's primarily the math subset of Latex so just because you can do something in Latex doesn't mean you can do it in Mathjax.

Comment: But looks like you can do it: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/newcommand.html and http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros.html. There are also quite a lot of questions on here if you Google "Mathjax newcommand".

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75585588/7669319